# Selenium IDE - Can I select a row based on column content to verify other columns?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am testing an application using Selenium IDE. There is a table with unstable row ordering - which means the elements I need to verify are in different rows on each test run.

I'd like to use text known to be in the first column to find the row; and then verify the other columns in the same row.

The test looks like this:

```
store        || //form/table                    || tableXpath
store        || 3                               || initialsRow
verifyTable  || ${tableXpath}.${initialsRow}.0  || Initials
verifyTable  || ${tableXpath}.${initialsRow}.1  || MJ
verifyTable  || ${tableXpath}.${initialsRow}.2  || MH
```

Instead of hard-coding the "initialsRow" value; is it not possible to find the row index dynamically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I found was to use the Selenium's `storeElementIndex` command. It gets the index of an HTML element relative to its parent.

See http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html

I changed the test as follows:

```
store             || //form/table                                 || tableXpath
storeElementIndex || ${tableXpath}//tr/td[text() = "Initials"]/.. || initialsRow
verifyTable       || ${tableXpath}.${initialsRow}.1               || MJ
verifyTable       || ${tableXpath}.${initialsRow}.2               || MH
```

The XPath query `//form/table//tr/td[text() = "Initials"]/..` finds the 'tr' element above the 'td' element containing the text "Initials". Selenium stores the index of this 'tr' element relative to whatever its parent element is.

Comment: @Dawie...it seems like storeElementIndex is deprecated in 3.17 of the IDE...any idea what's the alternative?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, now I found, selenium CAN calculate. Unfortunately not implicitly like `${tableXpath}.${initialsRow + 1}.1` .
So I added an additional command:

```
storeEval || ${ORBInitialPort} + 1 || ORBInitialPortRow
```

and used `ORBInitialPortRow` instead of `ORBInitialPort` as index.

Comment: @Karsten...it seems like storeElementIndex has been deprecated...any idea what's the alternative?